# GET, if, elseif

Tags: php, get, if-statement

I've got one if, and one else in my script.

But I need something else for a $_GET statement so when people visit: URL.com/lol?code=23oojdosagodsj (or something like that) then I can do something inside (like an if, else).

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
    echo $_GET['code'];
}
```

I've tried that, but it just redirects me to the else statement which shows the form. 
I used: ?code=lol

Comment: Not understanding the question sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
    echo $_GET['code'];
}
```

the `echo` statement will be executed if and only if you've provided a `code` variable in a GET-request. (like page.php?code=whatever).

**From discussion below:** It's the URL-rewriting mechanism that is causing the error. Disabling URL-rewriting solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. password?code=lol takes me to the form.

Comment: Check the source of the generated page, and you should see that you have the string `"lol"` in there.

Comment: Check that 1) You're editing the right file and that the change takes effect (change the `if` to `if (true)` ...  2) Check that the `if` is actually executed (do `echo "I'm here!" right *above* the if-statement)

Comment: Then either you have overridden the GET variable by doing something like `$_GET = ....` in the code, or you have not provided a `code` argument in the GET request.

Comment: The only $_GET I have in my code is     print_r($_GET);
if(isset($_GET['code'])) 
 {
  echo $_GET['code'];
 }
and URL is: password?code=lol Also, how do you use that code formatting? ;x

Comment: if you don't have `password.php?code=lol` I assume you have some url-rewriting going on... This is probably related to your problem. Turn it off to debug.

Comment: Ah yes, that works. Is there any way I could get around this?

Comment: Can't answer without insight in the rewriting engine you're using. Please post a new question with this information (as this discussion is getting sort of off-topic to what you originally posted).

Comment: Not quite sure how, but I clicked yes for the Feedback bit if that's what you wanted