# GET, URL-Rewrite

Tags: php, url, get, url-rewriting

Continued from my previous thread: [GET, if, elseif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762491/get-if-elseif)

I'm using a CMS but it has URL rewrite somewhere through the files. 
How would I go around getting the    $_GET to work without the .php extension?

```
Options +MultiViews
```

That still won't let me visit /something.php it says not found. (Would it be because the pages aren't in /, they are in another directory using a template system?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache HTTP server, then you should consider to use [multiview option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews).
No need to use **RewriteRule** there.
In the htaccess file, add :

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use that. Read the edited post for my .htaccess.

Comment: You don't need RewriteRule, see the doc.

Comment: No. That is the .htaccess that came with the CMS. I understand that I don't need the RewriteRule, but I'm not sure how I'd convert it.